# error on load RestClient on Azure devops extension dev

Tags: azure-devops

Im new in extensión dev for #azure #DevOps, I already publish one, the extensión by now can save and get documents via

```
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (
    dataService: any
  ) {...});
```

I want to get all teams from the project,and I have 2 problems,  First I try to import the Rest client like this:

```
import RestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");
```

But, When I upload to azure Devops and display the page in the consle say:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at index.js:1:1
```

Second I dont relly know how to use the getTeams function, I try this, but I can not test it, If u could give me an example would be great

```
var client = RestClient.getClient();
client.getTeams(VSS.getWebContext().project.id).then(function(getTeams){console.log(getTeams)})
```

I try another API and it works like this:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"], function (VSS_Service:any, TFS_Wit_WebApi:any) {
  // Get the REST client
  var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
  // ...
  console.log("obtiene cliente")
  witClient.getWorkItems(/* some work item IDs */ [1,2,3,4], ["System.Title"]).then(
    function(workItems:any) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(workItems));
    });
});
```

But, It doesnt work when I try my first aproach, like this:
import RestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");

I try to check my config files but dont know what to do, I have this in my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0"
  },
```

and in my file tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "lib": ["es5",
            "es6",
            "dom"],
    "module": "amd",  
    "types": ["vss-web-extension-sdk"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
}
```